# Magento 2 Update Shipping Rates when remove Products from Mini cart in Checkout Page via JS

Tags: magento2, checkout, shipping, mini-cart, checkout-page

I have created a shipping rule with certain products so that such products have free shipping, but for example when I delete the product in the checkout cart from the mini cart, the shipping cost is not updated until I click on the Checkout button.

Is there a way to update the shipping rates using js when the product is removed from the mini cart?